# Replace string with one word based on condition in python

Tags: python-3.x, string, pandas, replace

In a pandas dataframe, I have a string column with multiple values and I want to replace it one with based on a match for different rows.

[image]

Eg - Based on image, I want to specify "Extreme progressive,Progressive rock,Progressive" as Progressive, "Heavy,Bay area thrash" as Thrash, "Progressive death,Death,Progressive thrash" as Death and so on. How should I proceed with executing the same?

Answer (score 1):

Using a dataframe:

```
dfa:

        ID No   Time    Variable    Val
0       123     0.1     A           1
1       123     0.1     B           2
2       123     0.1     C           3
3       127     0.8     A           4
4       127     0.8     B           5
5       127     0.8     C           6
```

you can create a dict mapper:

```
dictMapper = {'A' : 'aye', 'B': 'bee'}
dfa['Variable'] = dfa['Variable'].map(lambda x: dictMapper.get(x,x))
dfa:
    ID No   Time    Variable    Val
0   123     0.1     aye         1
1   123     0.1     bee         2
2   123     0.1     C           3
3   127     0.8     aye         4
4   127     0.8     bee         5
5   127     0.8     C           6
```

This ofcourse relies on you knowing all before: after combinations before updating your dataframe as you'll need an exact match to the dict keys.

Comment: This works, though all the necessary combinations are required in this case. How to proceed if one decides on replacing the string with a word based on a match in the string?

Comment: you'll still need some form of maping dict I assume. You could split the string on commas and check each word against the dict.keys